# xcode 8 input field action not showing event dropdown

Tags: swift, xcode, text

I'm a beginner at xcode.

I am following a tutorial here: http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2015/7/24/how-to-get-uitextfield-text-changed-events-for-your-validation-logic-swift-tips-1

However, when I try creating the action for the "text field", the drop popup isn't the same for me in xcode 8.2 and doesn't give option to select "event".

This should be seen:

[image]

But I see this instead:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature changed now?

Answer (score 2):

Its changed now, but you can still access it from built in functions for textfield. IE. **textFieldDidEndEditing** or even **textFieldDidBeginEditing** if you prefer. Here is how that tut will look then:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("textField: \(textField.text)")

    if validatePassword(textField.text) {
        // correct password
        button.enabled = true
    } 
    else {
        button.enabled = false
    }
}

func validatePassword(text: String) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    // test password
    if text == "Secret!" {
        result = true
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: I need to simply add this code in viewcontroller? how will it hook up?

Comment: Once you have added the link to the viewController, you will need to add ,UITextFieldDelegate after UIViewController in your class declaration and it will pick up that it is the only textfield.

Comment: ok let me try that, also, is blue viewcontroller icon and yellow the same?

Comment: nope, Yellow should be the controller while blue is just a view.

Comment: in the images in my question, the tutorial guys controller has yellow button, mine is blue, that's what i'm asking :/ are they same?

Comment: What does it say next to object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131173/discussion-between-aman77-and-nabeel-khan).